# SVN does not see conflicts between original folder and moved version

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, tree-conflict

I have a folder in trunk with old directory structure, and branch where several directories were grouped as subfolders of new folder:

```
old(trunk) > root/dirA
                 /dirB
                 /dirC

new(branch) > root/dirGROUP/dirA
                           /dirB
                           /dirC
```

In `new` directories was moved with `svn move` command.

There are text conflicts exist between files of old `dirA` and new `dirA.`
And when I do `svn merge --reintegrate http://url.to.the.branch` SVN just deletes old `dirA`, `dirB`, `dirC` and gives me just new directory structure, without noticing conflicts between files of old and new `dirA` versions as if it was independent directories. Files in new `dirA` were merged with `A` status.
Does SVN supports such merges by default? If yes it turns out that I missed something
If no - how to teach SVN to notice this conflicts?

Answer (score 3):

This might help now, I have two solutions for this.The problem you faced can be overcome with these approach.

Solution1 :

Say you have following files

```
/branch/foo/src/com
/branch/foo/test/com
/trunk/src/main/java/com
/trunk/src/test/java/com
```

Before you moved src/com to src/main/java/com and test/com to src/test/java/com you could have done:

```
cd $TRUNK
svn merge -r N:M http://server/branch/foo .
```

What you could do now is:

```
cd $TRUNK
svn merge -r N:M http://server/branch/foo/src/com src/main/java/com
svn merge -r N:M http://server/branch/foo/test/com src/test/java/com
```

OR what else you could have done is

Solution2 :

1) Do svn up to get latest copy of code ( in old dir structure)

```
svn up
```

2) copy dirs with unix commands in dir dir stucture

```
cp -r /root/dirA /root/dirGroup/
cp -r /root/dirB /root/dirGroup/
cp -r /root/dirC /root/dirGroup/
```

Now you have local copy in your desired path.

3) Delete the old files.

```
svn -d file names.
svn ci
```

4) Add new files an d dirs
    svn add dirA
    svn add dirB
    svn add dirC
    svn ci for all three dir

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! Ive decided that I would just use secondary `mercurial` repo for such merges =))) Could you clarify - assuming 'strict' approach to do merge, that I described in Q - we must not expect, that SVN will recognize conflicts between original folders and moved ones, because SVN just not able to do such merges right (without tricks such as you described)?